# JAVA_HOME: unbound variable while running a script in Jenkins

Tags: bash, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, devops, jenkins-groovy

The build script has the following lines :

```
if [ -z "$JAVA_HOME" ]; then
       export JAVA_HOME="$(dirname "$(dirname "$(readlink -e "$(type -p "javac")")")")"
       echo "JAVA_HOME=$JAVA_HOME"
 fi
```

which runs well when placed in sh " ", but when placed in a bash file and while running it, throws an error:

```
stage ('Build') {
      sh '''
                    if [ -z "$JAVA_HOME" ]; then
                    export JAVA_HOME="$(dirname "$(dirname "$(readlink -e "$(type -p "javac")")")")"
                    echo "JAVA_HOME=$JAVA_HOME"
                     fi
                    sudo bash ./build 
            '''
```

}

Console Output:

```
+ '[' -z /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.232.b09-0.el7_7.x86_64 ']'
+ sudo bash ./build
running: ./build 
+ trap '>&2 echo '\''ERR'\'' && exit -1' ERR
./build: line 10: JAVA_HOME: unbound variable
```

Comment: the pipeline looks good, what do you have in ./build?

Comment: build contains " if [ -z "$JAVA_HOME" ]; then
                    export JAVA_HOME="$(dirname "$(dirname "$(readlink -e "$(type -p "javac")")")")"
                    echo "JAVA_HOME=$JAVA_HOME"
                     fi"  i just brought it out of the build script to show that it works well outside and not when the script is called

Answer (score 0):

I guess the exported variable is not passed to the new instance of bash you are spawning.

You could do `sudo su <myuser>` at the top of your script

```
                    sudo su myuser
                    if [ -z "$JAVA_HOME" ]; then
                    export JAVA_HOME="$(dirname "$(dirname "$(readlink -e "$(type -p "javac")")")")"
                    echo "JAVA_HOME=$JAVA_HOME"
                     fi
                    ./build
```

of course using sudo in your build is not recommended. A better alternative is to give to jenkins the permissions it needs to run your build

Comment: build contains ' if [ -z "$JAVA_HOME" ]; then export JAVA_HOME="$(dirname "$(dirname "$(readlink -e "$(type -p "javac")")")")" echo "JAVA_HOME=$JAVA_HOME" fi' i just brought it out of the build script to show that it works well outside and not when the script is called. Basically the JAVA_HOME is not passed to the build script which checks for $JAVA_HOME, not sure if i can try injecting the variable, also i'm not sure how its possible to inject in Pipeline script.

Comment: did you try my solution? To inject a variable environment to a whole pipeline you could use groovy: `env.JAVA_HOME = "/java/path"`

Comment: Yes i did try switching user, but the outcome was the same, and also i try setting as env, got the below error : env.JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.232.b09-0.el7_7.x86_64
/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/int-ing@tmp/durable-d0344183/script.sh: line 24: env.JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.232.b09-0.el7_7.x86_64: No such file or directory, but this dir does exist !

Answer (score 0):

You most likely have something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

set -euo pipefail

run_build_script
```

set is a built in command for modifying the behavior of the shell itself. And it is important to understand the options. If you happen to have set the **u** option, then you get the above error for obvious reason (see below).

> **e**:    Exit script immediately if any command returns a non-zero exit status.
>   **u**:    Exit script immediately if an undefined variable is used (e.g. echo "$UNDEFINED_ENV_VAR").
>
> **o**: pipefail   Ensure Bash pipelines (e.g. cmd | othercmd) return a non-zero status if any of the commands fail, rather than returning the
>   exit status of the last command in the pipeline.
>   **x**:    Expand and print each command before executing. See Debugging your environment for more information.

To solve this, either remove the u options from the set command or wrap only part of the code that is causing the error between ***set +u and set -u.***

```
set +u
if [ -z "$JAVA_HOME" ]; then
       export JAVA_HOME="$(dirname "$(dirname "$(readlink -e "$(type -p "javac")")")")"
       echo "JAVA_HOME=$JAVA_HOME"
 fi
set -u
```